# Why are linux system calls different across architectures

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, riscv

According to this [system calls table](https://marcin.juszkiewicz.com.pl/download/tables/syscalls.html), linux system calls are different across architecture, but IMO syscalls are higher level encapsulation which do not depent on any specific architechture. Why is it designed this way?

In a specific case, riscv64 linux doesn't have `mkdir`, instead it has `mkdirat`, but weirdly it doesn't have `rmdir` or `rmdirat`, how could it implement `/bin/rmdir` without `rmdir`, even if it could (via other syscalls like `read` and `write`), why not do the same for `mkdir`? It's really confusing that these two syscalls don't match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at this from the wrong direction. `mkdirat` can do everything that `mkdir` can do and then some, so the question isn't why riscv64 *doesn't* have `mkdir`, but rather why x86 *does* have it. The answer to that is backwards userspace compatibility. Since Linux never breaks that, and `mkdir` existed first, it will exist there forever. But riscv64 never had it, so there are no userspace programs for it to break by not having it.

As for `rmdir`, the replacement for that isn't `rmdirat`, but rather `unlinkat` with `AT_REMOVEDIR`. The same argument then applies to it.